Grub Cryptomount & Multiple Partitions in a LUKS container
It's possible to put multiple partitions in a LUKS (and LUKS2) container and, according to this question/answer, we can get it to work.  The question I have is whether on bootup there's some way to get grub's cryptomount to, besides unlocking the LUKS container, also identify the partitions and allow me to select one as /boot.

Consider using LVM instead of partitions inside LUKS?

LUKS has been rock stable for me, but I got badly burned by LVM once.  So I stay away from it.

Then use regular partitions and multiple LUKS containers? Partitions inside LUKS just isn't widely supported.

I know it's not widely supported, but I'm wondering whether there's a way to do it.

Just tried it. GRUB2 does seem to support partitions inside crypto devices just fine. So after cryptomount opens the device for you e.g. as (crypto0) you can access partitions and filesystems and files on it normally, e.g. as (crypto0,gpt3)/vmlinuz-linux. Exact syntax and paths will depend on your setup. Using this as /boot might be more involved, since all necessary modules and configs to reach must already be baked into Grub's core.img, and grub-install might not expect this constellation...

@frostschutz / many thanks for testing out out!  You're welcome to put an answer if you like, and I'll accept it.  (I've been trying to do the same, but stuck on cryptomount not even opening a test LUKS volume, with password "testme" - so it's not a keymap issue.  Once I get past that issue, I'll try the rest.)
